# Can Jmeter support an Openbravo web application which supports only Chrome browser?

Tags: performance, jmeter, openbravo

Need to do load test on a Openbravo POS application which only supports chrome browser. Can JMeter be recommended for this effort or is there any better opensource tool out there?

Comment: I could record the https traffic in Jmeter proxy and also in Blazemeter, but however while running the script, not able to see the response correctly as in browser. Have opted to download embedded resources too in https sampler.

Answer (score 1):

Looking into [WHY IS MY APPLICATION SLOW?](http://planet.openbravo.com/blog/why-is-my-application-slow/) post it should be possible to test Openbravo POS with JMeter.

In order to make JMeter to appear as Chrome for the Openbravo POS it should be sufficient to add a [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send [User-Agent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent) header with the value of the relevant [Chrome User Agent String](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/chrome/)

Comment: Yes, the official OpenBravo site does illustrate of using Jmeter for Performance testing. However, the element of doubt I've is what if the application supports only chrome browser, is it still recommendable to use Jmeter?.
I do have HTTP Header Manager in the Test Plan.